# react-router server rendering without matched component's html content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router 1.0.0-rc3, and following this [server rendering](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md) guide.

Here is the point part:

```
const html = renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
  </Provider>
);
```

Here is my route part:

```
  <Route path="/" component={Container} >
    <IndexRoute component={App} />
    <Route path=":source/:owner/:name/:branch/tree/:corpus*" component={App} />
    <Route path=":source/:owner/:name/:branch/ticket/(:ticket)" component={App} />
  </Route>
```

I got `html` output as an empty div element like:

`<div data-reactid=".whl3ehjj0g" data-react-checksum="12324050"></div>`

There is no `<App />` component rendered in the server, and the `<App />` rendered normally after receiving server rendering response in the client, and all the routes funtions work well in the client.

So, anything I missed?

Comment: It worked fine for me, though I'm using renderToStaticMarkup as I'm doing the whole html https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/blob/master/app/Router.js

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out, actually it's not related to react-router, it's cyclic dependencies in my code cause the problem. :(

Comment: can you elaborate? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @zackify see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/272#issuecomment-104320775 describe cyclic dependencies issue.

Comment: that wasn't the problem. See my response above ^

Answer (score 0):

My problem was doing require when I was doing `export default` in my component instead of `module.exports`. That fixed the issue for me!